# Discord.py I want to ping a certain role at every server my bot is in

Tags: python, discord.py

So i want to ping @Wafaduck Alerts in every server my bot is in. When I input my command on this specific server I can see the ping but when it's on a different server it shows @deleted role.

heres my code

```py
       @client.command() #v1
       @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
            async def ping(ctx, *, msg):
            role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name = 'Wafaduck Alerts')
            for guild in client.guilds:
                for channel in guild.channels:
                if(channel.name == 'wafaduck-alerts'):   
                    await channel.send(f"{role.mention}")
```

Comment: First of all don't use the commands.has_permissions(administrator=True). This will allow any admin in any server ping everyone with the role in all the other guilds the bot is in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to get the role from each iteration rather than from the command. As Malware also stated make sure you create your own permissions handling otherwise someone would be able to ping all the admins.

```py
       @client.command() #v1
       @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
       async def ping(ctx, *, msg):
            for guild in client.guilds:
                role = get(guild.roles, name = 'Wafaduck Alerts')
                for channel in guild.channels:
                    if(channel.name == 'wafaduck-alerts'):   
                        await channel.send(f"{role.mention}")
```

Comment: Hii! Im kinda new to coding. so What does Permission handling mean? and whatt do you mean by someone would be able to ping all the admins? Btw this is my first time using stackoverflow! and im loving it!

Comment: @Wafaduck You should look at creating a [Check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=check#checks) for permission handling where you return True/ False if the user is allowed to execute the command. Then by pinging all the admins is if someone is an admin of any discord server your bot is in, they can ping all the people in every server who holds that role

Comment: Ohh! Awesome thank you! Btw Can I ask another coding question here? or do I need to wait for a day for the next one. Because this is the final problem im struggling before I can let the bot out and running :D

Comment: @Wafaduck you must wait another day to ask another question if it not related to the current question. Also if I have solved your issue please mark this as correct